# Heroku slugsize error when slugsize is not full

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, webdeploy

Heroku keeps rejecting my build saying:

```
Compiled slug size: 820.1M is too large (max is 500M).
```

But, when I check slugsizing, here's what I get:

```
$ du -sh *
1.0K    Procfile
8.0K    __pycache__
20K     data_prep
4.0K    handler.py
44M     model
20K     parameters
4.0K    requirements.txt
1.0K    runtime.txt
```

And those files do not sum up to 820.1M. I've even created a new python 3.7 conda env and installed only 4 packages using pip: Numpy, Pandas, Flask and Geopy. Even so, the results don't change.

Here are all my requirements:

```
backcall==0.2.0
certifi==2020.12.5
click==7.1.2
cmdstanpy==0.9.5
colorama==0.4.4
convertdate==2.3.0
decorator==5.0.6
ephem==3.7.7.1
Flask==1.1.2
geographiclib==1.50
geopy==2.1.0
hijri-converter==2.1.1
holidays==0.10.5.2
ipykernel==5.5.3
ipython==7.22.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jedi==0.18.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
jupyter-client==6.1.12
jupyter-core==4.7.1
korean-lunar-calendar==0.2.1
LunarCalendar==0.0.9
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
numpy==1.20.2
pandas==1.2.4
parso==0.8.2
pickleshare==0.7.5
pip==21.0.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.18
Pygments==2.8.1
PyMeeus==0.3.7
pystan==2.19.1.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2021.1
pyzmq==22.0.3
setuptools==52.0.0
setuptools-git==1.2
six==1.15.0
tornado==6.1
traitlets==5.0.5
wcwidth==0.2.5
Werkzeug==1.0.1
wheel==0.36.2
wincertstore==0.2
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

- Add `.slugignore` to ignore the files that are not useful. `_pycache_` can be ignored here.
- It's possible that before you added the .slugignore file you had some large files added to the git repo and now they are in the slug cache or as git refs.

**You can remove the cache using the `heroku-repo` plugin**

#### Install the plugin using the command

```sh
$ heroku plugins:install heroku-repo
```

#### gc

```sh
$ heroku repo:gc -a appname
```

This will run a `git gc --aggressive` against the applications repo. This is done inside a run process on the application.

#### purge-cache

```sh
$ heroku repo:purge_cache -a appname
```

This will delete the contents of the build cache stored in the repository. This is done inside a run process on the application.

After following these steps you may push your code to the `Heroku`.

If it does not work then maybe your `requirements.txt` files are large in size such that it crosses the slug size limit.

Comment: When using repo I'm having the following error: `The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found after running heroku repo:gc -a` maybe because this built would be my first build in the app, and it's empty. One thing I didn't mention is that the folder I'm in is a folder within the git folder, is there a chance that even if I'm making the push from the current folder all the files from the git folder are being pushed as well?

Comment: the only folder that is pushed will. be the current directory. If it's not working then your dependencies are of very large size so that they are crossing the limit of slug size.